# Kafka-connect external broker architecture

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-blob-storage, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to connect kafka-connect(deployment by docker-compose) to consume from an external broker to upload to azure blob storage. How does my docker-compose should be look like? Do I need internal kafka broker for the internal topics? CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS variable points out to which broker? local or remote?
P.S: the remote broker required SASL authentication. How should I provide the credentials? In the body of creating connector or CONNECT_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG in kafka-connect container env var?
I am a little bit confused!

[Current payload](https://pastebin.com/0entmwd6)

CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS is my local cluster. while `confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers` in payload of creating connector point out to the remote broker. If this is the case, how should I set auth credentials in payload?